# Webpack can't resolve @ (alias) imports used inside a library

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, require

Webpack is throwing this error: `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@/utils/index'`.

[image]

Here's the nippy rundown:

- This failing import above is made within the node library [`vue2-datepicker`](https://github.com/mengxiong10/vue2-datepicker).
- This date picker is used in a component, which is in turn registered to Vue in the entry script using `require.context('base^/components/', true, /\.vue$/i)`.
- This was working before when the entry script wasn't using require.context: `import Component from "base^/components/component"`.

I have tried changing the `./webpack.config.js` @ alias, but without effect. Do you have any ideas what's wrong?

Here's the rundown of imports:

[image]